# How to plot actual year in x axis of r plot instead of year 0,1,2......20

Tags: r

I am newbie in R. please show me the correct link if I asked my question in wrong forum. I am reading and extracting data from netcdf file. I want to plot actual year i.e. 1980,1981,......1999 in x-axis instead of 0,1,...20. I tried to change the range using xrange or xaxt and axis command in plot but unable to do so.Also, I want to plot the lines between 1980-1999 buthttps://i.stack.imgur.com/z8sEL.png the line continues after 1999 (see image) I tried since last 7 days without any succes and could not concentrate and move on. I have copied partial code and image. I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
 for (j in 1:length(station_rchid)){
   for (i in 1:length(rchid)){
      if(identical(station_rchid[j],rchid[i])){
         windows()
         per<-'Average Annual '
         an_time<-1:nyear
         heading <- paste(per,vari,tper,station_name[j])
         yrange<- max(varX_year[1,,j],varX_year[2,,j])
         plot(an_time,varX_year[1,,j],main=heading,type="l",ylim=c(0,yrange),xlab="Year",ylab=unity,col="red",cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.5)
         lines(an_time,varX_year[2,,j],col="blue")
         legend("topleft", c("Pred","Obs"),lty=c(1,1),lwd=c(2.5,2.5), col=c("red","blue"),inset = 1.4)
         filename<-paste("NZ_Annual_swe_",station_name[i],".xls")
#         write.xls(varX_year[ , ,j],file=filename,colNames=TRUE,rowNames=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to remove the axes in the `plot` and then re-add them later. The `pretty` can help you automate the label placements. Parse all axis-options to the `axis` lines.

```
plot(an_time, varX_year, main = heading, type="l", ylim = c(0,yrange)
     ,xlab = "Year", ylab = unity, col = "red", cex.lab = 1.5,
     ,axes = FALSE)
axis(1, at = pretty(an_time), labels = pretty(an_time) + 1980, cex.axis=1.5)
axis(2, cex.axis=1.5,)
box()
```

Be cautious with this approach, since you only change the labels.
Another workaround I suppose could be just to add 1980 to the year vector, i.e.

```
an_time <- an_time + 1980
```